# Concatenate multiple commands into a single line of result

Tags: awk

I'm trying to display on a single row the available space versus total space of all my mnt folders.

I'm using this command:

```
(df -h| grep 'mnt' | awk '{s+=$4} END {print s}') ; (df -h| grep 'mnt' | awk '{s+=$3} END {print s}')
```

Unfortunately it produces 2 lines of output:

```
383
850
```

I'd like to build a command that ouputs someting like

```
383/850
```

I feel like **awk** is the way, but the documentation of said command lost me

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '/mnt/ { s+=$4 ; t+=$3 } END {print s"/"t}' <(df -h)
383/850
```